# Hugo: How to set dict value by interpolation?

Tags: dictionary, interpolation, hugo, go-templates

In Go (Hugo) templates, how can I set the value of a single entry in a `dict`?

In this example, I start with a pre-populated `dict` `$vitality` and maybe a string `.Params.vitality`. If the string has anything, I'd like to set the `dict` entry that the string is the key to to 1.

```html
<figure class="histogram">
{{ $vitality := (dict 
    "institutional" .Params.count_institutional 
    "stable" .Params.count_stable 
    "endangered" .Params.count_endangered 
    "dying" .Params.count_dying 
    "extinct" .Params.count_extinct) 
}}
{{ if ne .Params.vitality "" }}
    {{ $vitality.(.Params.vitality) <!--problem line-->
        := .Params.vitality 
    }} 
{{ end }}
{{ range $key, $value := $vitality }}
    <div class="histogram-bar" 
         data-category="{{ $key }}" 
         data-count="{{ $value }}">
        <div class="histogram-bar-label">{{ $key }}</div>
    </div>
{{ end }}
</figure>
```

This doesn't parse, with Hugo choking on the first `.` in `$vitality.(.Params.vitality)`. I believe this attempt is called interpolation, and the goal isn't possible without interpolation. Is it possible in Go templates, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are wanting to add `.Params.vitality` to the `$vitality` dict. I think what you want is [merge](https://gohugo.io/functions/merge/). Your problem line becomes.

```
$vitality = merge $vitality(dict "vitality" .Params.vitality)
```

Comment: I think it'd be more like `$vitality = merge $vitality (dict .Params.vitality 1)`, but that's giving me a compile error "invalid dictionary key "